# Link .lib file Windows Octave

Tags: octave

I am trying to compile some code using Octave and I need to link some .lib files. I can't seem to get the link to work properly and when I compile I am getting errors about references to functions that don't exist. This is what lead me to believe that my links are not working.

this is the command I am running:

`mex -v someFile.cpp -IC:\path\to\includes -LC:\path\to\libs -lmylib.lib`

I am running Octave 3.2.4 in Windows.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. My path to the libs parameter in that command line string needed to be before the file name. The following works:

`mex -v -IC:\path\to\includes -LC:\path\to\libs someFile.cpp -lmylib.lib`